# How to update id field to same value and then automatically increment it?

Tags: oracle, jsp

Is there any way to update id column to same value for certain rows and the automatically increment it for other certain rows and so on? As I am trying to provide same order id to orders placed on the same date and then automatically increment it for the other date.Totally new to oracle!

This is what I want:

```
 order id |album | order date|status|user
       1  | yuan | 13-07-17  |final |xyz
       1  | ibuki| 13-07-17  |final |xyz
       2  | ibuki| 13-07-17  |final |abc
       3  | ibuki| 14-07-17  |final |xyz
       3  | ibuki| 14-07-17  |final |xyz
```

And this is what I got:

```
 order id |album | order date|status|user
       1  | yuan | 13-07-17  |final |xyz
       1  | ibuki| 13-07-17  |final |xyz
       1  | ibuki| 13-07-17  |final |abc
       1  | ibuki| 14-07-17  |final |xyz
       1  | ibuki| 14-07-17  |final |xyz
```

Actually I am unable to think of a query!

Comment: Hi Raj, you need to go have a read through [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it is almost always necessary to post code. It shows people that you have put effort into your question, and it will definitely make them more likely to help you.

Comment: At the very least, please post a sample of the starting data set, the matching desired finishing data set and the rules required to transform the one into the other.

Comment: @APC I edited my question. Thanks in advance.